# FTL log in OFBiz

Tags: ofbiz

I am new to `OFBiz` and I want to keep log of FTL files after it is rendered, to be more elaborate i want to know what file is returned from FTL engine in OFBiz. Example:

```
  <#if sessionAttributes.autoName?has_content>
    <h2>  ${sessionAttributes.autoName?html}
      &nbsp;<a href="<@ofbizUrl>autoLogout</@ofbizUrl>" class="linktext">Logout</a></h2>
    <#else/>
      ${uiLabelMap.CommonWelcome}!
    </#if>  i want to know what will this code return .
```

I have no idea how to do it and i didn't try any thing yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your requirement right but you can set `widget.verbose=true` in widget.properties to see the screen/ftl boundaries in the generated results. Just view the source code in your browser after the screen is rendered.